# Using Process.Start to open explorer

Tags: c#, explorer

Edit: solution found, will note under image at the end of the question

After a bunch of research here on SO, I found that the way to open explorer with a selected file was:

`Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select, " + path);`

However when I do this with controlled input, Explorer opens just its main window, however when I harcode the function call to the same value that's in the path variable (In my control test its a text file in C:\Temp) it works. So if I do the above when path is "C:\Temp\test.txt" It does't open explorer in the temp folder, however when I do:

`Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select, C:\\Temp\\test.txt");`

It works perfectly, opening explorer and highlighting the file. What is happening here? Is there something wrong with the internal formatting on my string variable or something?

(Additionally, I ran into the same issue using the path variable to open a FileInfo. Hardcoded to the same value would work, but using the variable gave me a "the given path's format is not supported" exception")

Image showing that path and the harcoded value are the same:
[image: Image showing that path and the harcoded value are the same]

The 2 explorer windows (cropped for Security) are the results of the 2 respective calls. The one with the variable shows te basic explorer main page. The one that's hardcoded shows the file selected as expected.

Edit: There was a hidden Left-To-Right Format character hidden in the front of the string.

Comment: `"C:\\Temp\\test.txt" != "C:\Temp\test.txt"` does it work if you use the same value for `path`?

Comment: What *exactly* is the value of path? You are working with strings. And strings are notoriously likely to not match. As "\" is the String Escape Character as well as a possible Path Seperator, "C:\Temp\test.txt" is something very different from "C:\\Temp\\test.txt".

Comment: When checked in the Debugger: `path` is "C:\\Temp\\test.txt" I chose my value for the hardcode based on what I saw in the variable in the debugger, and copied it exactly

Comment: That's pretty much impossible with the given code - if `path` in the first sample equals the hardcoded string in the second sample, then the behavior will be identical. Please post an example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @RufusL I added an image showing that Path and the Hardcoded string are the same. The 2 cropped Explorer windows are the Respective results of the 2 calls. (Images cropped for Security reasons)

Comment: All I'm saying is that I created a `C:\Temp\test.txt` file and ran your code both ways, and got the same results each time, so something else is going on. Where are you getting the `path` string from? Could it have a strange character that doesn't appear in the UI?

Comment: *"Is there something wrong with the internal formatting on my string variable or something"* Yes, most likely.

Comment: @RufusL There was a hidden AScii 8234 Character. It was being taken from a WPF control that was loaded from a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Explore("C:\\Users\\art_g\\Desktop\\Sample.txt");
        }
        static void Explore(string path) =>
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select, " + path);
    }
```

**Works like a charm. Check your path string.**